# Implementation of PayPal EWP in PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I'm new to the integration of PayPal in PHP. 
I found some [tutorial](https://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php) and I followed it. 
Now, I'm having problems with sandbox:

`The email address for the business is not present in the encrypted blob. Please contact your merchant.`

I have tried sending e-mail and Merchant ID of my Sandbox account, but no luck.

My code:

```
define("SANDBOX", 1);

$bussiness_id="paypal@***********";
if(SANDBOX) $bussiness_id="***********";
```

The data to be encrypted:

```
$form = array('cmd' => '_s-xclick',
        'cert_id' => '*************',
        'business' => $bussiness_id,
        'custom' => 'test',
        //'invoice' => '...',
        'currency_code' => 'EUR',
        'no_shipping' => '1',
        'item_name' => 'TestItem',
        'item_number' => '12345',
        'amount' => '10'
    );

$encrypted = paypal_encrypt($form);

function paypal_encrypt($hash)
{

    ...trimmed...

    $data = "";
    foreach ($hash as $key => $value) {
        if ($value != "") {
            //echo "Adding to blob: $key=$value\n";
            $data .= "$key=$value\n";
        }
    }

    $openssl_cmd = "($OPENSSL smime -sign -signer $MY_CERT_FILE -inkey $MY_KEY_FILE " .
                        "-outform der -nodetach -binary <<_EOF_\n$data\n_EOF_\n) | " .
                        "$OPENSSL smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE";

    exec($openssl_cmd, $output, $error);

    ...trimmed...
};
?>
```

The PayPal form is:

```
<form action="https://<?php if(SANDBOX) echo "www.sandbox"; else echo "www"; ?>.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target=_blank>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="<?php echo $encrypted; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Pay">
</form>
```

The code is just a sample from the tutorial, I haven't edited it too much.

Comment: did you include that email address in the sandbox account?

Comment: @SirGalahad I did. It is the only email in the sandbox account.

Comment: umm, the way I see it, it can have a couple problems: 1. cert or key file may not be read properly(lacking permission etc.) 2.your OPENSSL version may have problem . For number 1, var dump the variables , number 2 you just have to copy the command to command line and see what comes out

Comment: I see no problems running it from shell: https://paste.ee/p/r8YuL

Comment: @SirGalahad my OpenSSL version: "OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017"

Comment: have you tried using the official paypal php package using composer ? Not too sure about what is going on, but official packages usually are easier to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the encryption is not necessary as long as you are checking the IPN requests.

I implemented the payment form without any kind of encryption and when IPN came, I check it against the database and PayPal.

If everything matches, I update the DB and mark order as paid. If there are differences, I just log everything and email myself about the issue.